# REACTJS - Import CKEditor 5 from online build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I got stuck at import the CUSTOM CKEditor 5 to ReactJS. I had already searching the docs but it seems to hard to understand.

First, I go to the Onine Builder in here: https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/  and  download the zip file.

Then, in this zip file, I have the build folder (contains ckeditor.js, ckeditor.js.map and the translation folder). Copy all the contents in this folder to /src/compoments/CKeditor (to import in React).

And import it like this

```
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react"; (install via npm)
import ClassicEditor from "./components/ckeditor/ckeditor"; (import from zip file)
```

And I have this error. Please let me know how to install CkEditor in ReactJS.

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should add the content of the zip file to the root of your project like this:

```
├── ckeditor5
│   ├── build
│   ├── sample
│   ├── src
│   ├── ...
│   ├── package.json
│   └── webpack.config.js
├── node_modules
├── public
├── src
├── ...
└── package.json
```

Then run this command `yarn add file:./ckeditor5` or `npm add file:./ckeditor5`.
Now you can use your custom Editor in this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'

const editorConfiguration = {
    toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic' ]
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h2>Using CKEditor 5 from online builder in React</h2>
                <CKEditor
                    editor={ Editor }
                    config={ editorConfiguration }
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                    onReady={ editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    } }
                    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                    } }
                    onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
                    } }
                    onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
                    } }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but I get the following error `CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules`

Comment: I am getting this err. Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: For anyone looking for documentation, [official docs here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html#using-the-editor-with-collaboration-plugins).

Comment: Yes, to those facing problem, let me share my solution, I built it using the online building tool, imported it in my project, and uninstalled the ClassicEditor and referenced the custom build in package.json

Comment: I got this err `TypeError: this.props.editor.create is not a function` after follow steps :((

Comment: I got this error following the steps TypeError: a.clone is not a function

Answer (score 4):

There are two scenarios where you need to change your custom build time to time. In that case, either you can keep on publishing on npm after running

```
npm run build
```

on your custom build or you can keep that in your github and install using

```sh
npm install git+git@github.com:<your username>/<custom ckeditor>.git
```

You can rename the name so that whenever you install it goes into

`node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-custom-build`

```js
{
  "name": "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-custom-build",
   ....
}
```

Now you need to **import** like this

```js
import { Editor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-custom-build';
```

And thus all your code would look like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import { Editor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-custom-build';

export const  CkEditor =  () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h2>Using CKEditor 5 build in React</h2>
        <CKEditor
            data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
            onReady={ editor => {
                // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
            } }
            onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                const data = editor.getData();
                console.log( {"data": data } );
            } }
            onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
                console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
            } }
            onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
                console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
            } }
        />
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial and got an import error, and fixed it as follows

```
import { Editor } from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
```

thanks you for this suport

> S. Hesam

[image: Editor]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Add eslint disabled at the top, like this

/* eslint-disabled */

your code of ckeditor.js inside build/ckeditor.js

/* eslint-enabled */