# macOS npm, works on linux: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ckeditor5/build/ckeditor'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ckeditor, npm-install, ckeditor5

I've added a custom build of CKEditor to my ReactJS app as described in the [answers to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62243323/reactjs-import-ckeditor-5-from-online-build).

**ReactComponent.tsx**

```
import Editor from 'ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';
```

**package.json**

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^5",
"ckeditor5-custom-build": "file:ckeditor5",
```

A CKEditor5 custom build [created with the custom tool](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) is in the `ckeditor5` directory and I have run `npm run build` in the `ckeditor5` directory to build ckeditor5. The build successfully completed.

However, when I run `npm run serve` in the root directory to start my ReactJS app (with CRA, create-react-app), I get the following error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/components/ReactComponent.tsx 11:0-46

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ckeditor5/build/ckeditor' in '/Users/private/app/src/components'
```

This app was successfully built on Linux, but I just moved it to macOS.  I ran `npm update` and I see that in `package-lock.json`, all the CKEditor-related files have been removed.  So for some reason, npm on macOS is not seeing the CKEditor5 custom build, and I don't know how to fix this.

Running npm 9.2.0 via homebrew, the latest version as of writing. Ventura on Apple Silicon.

**Edit**

I can get the app running by removing the line `"ckeditor5-custom-build": "file:ckeditor5",` from `package.json` and using `npm link` like this:

```
cd ckeditor5
npm link
cd ../
npm link ckeditor5-custom-build
```

However, now eslint complains when I import because of extraneous dependencies.  I can turn this warning off because the app works, but to avoid setup issues in the future, I want to find a way to get the import working from the local build of ckeditor5 as I asked in the original question.